# bulk insert rowterminator not working properly

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I am trying to import csv (1 million records) file to sql server table using bulk insert

Example of the csv data is as below:

```
"Phone Numbers","Opstype"
"9827259163","D"
"9827961481","D"
"9827202228","A"
"9827529897","A"
"9827700249","A"
```

Screenshot from Notepad++:

[image]

My BULK INSERT code is as below

```
BULK INSERT dbo.tbl_dnd FROM "C:\DND_1.csv" WITH (DATAFILETYPE='char',FIRSTROW=2,FIELDTERMINATOR='","',ROWTERMINATOR='"\n"');
```

the result is as below from sql server (example):

```
Phone Numbers   Opstype
1120029090  A"  "9868321244 
1120220004  A"  "9868863100 
1120291549  A"  "9868843285 
1120299308  A"  "9868908545 
1120314169  A"  "9868929393 
1120502244  A"  "1122230590 
1120907054  A"  "1126148672 
1122029480  A"  "9868545672 
1122070793  A"  "9868541277 
1122078765  A"  "9968140674
```

Screenshot from sqlserver table:

[image]

Please also note that total records in sql server table after bulk insert is 500,000 records only. (Half the expected)

What am I doing wrong?

I am expecting to see only letters in Opstype without numbers and quotes

Comment: Check those rows in the csv file. Are there missing `"` or `,` characters? Are the row terminators always actually `\n` or are any `\r\n`? (Make sure you check with a decent text editor that actually shows the actual control characters, not just Notepad or Write. I recommend Notepad++, programmersnotepad, or a Linux command line editor)

Comment: no all same nothing is different

Comment: Wait, why have you got two types of quotes around the field and row terminators??? `'","'` should just be `','`

Comment: csv: "9827259163","D" . so fieldterminator is ","  while rowterminator should be the " at the end followed by \n followed by " for the double quotes at the beginning of the phone number of the second row.

Comment: No. Absolutely not. The `"` is the field quote character, `,` is the field terminator. You need both in csv files incase a field value includes a comma (field terminators between field quote characters are ignored). Take the `"` characters out of the terminators.

Comment: BULK INSERT dbo.tbl_dnd FROM "C:\DND_1.csv" WITH (DATAFILETYPE='char',FIRSTROW=2,FIELDQUOTE='"',FIELDTERMINATOR=',',ROWTERMINATOR='\n');      Resulted: Phone Number:"1120029090" Opstype: "A"  "9868321244"

Comment: Save a copy of the file with the header and exactly three rows of data.  Try to `BULK LOAD` that file, into an ***empty*** test table.  Take a screen shot of the loaded data, in the table.  Open the sample file with Notepad++, then enable `View`->`Show Symbol`->`Show All Characters` and take another screenshot.  Include both screenshots in your question.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? i.e.: what's the output from `SELECT @@VERSION`? Starting with SQL Server 2017 `BULK INSERT` has a `FORMAT='CSV'` option that allows it to deal with quotes and RFC4180-style files, ref: [FORMAT = 'CSV'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql#format--csv).

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 - I tired to use Format='CSV' however Bulk Insert Failed : Cannot obtain the required interface  "IID_IColumnsInfo"

Answer (score 0):

Your data contains CR LF as the row terminator.

Your BULK INSERT statement only has LF (`\n`).

You ***need*** `'\r\n'` as the row terminator.

(And to remove the `"` from your field and row terminators.)

Comment: Error: ODBC --call faild . The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 3. ```BULK INSERT dbo.tbl_dnd FROM "C:\Personal\Freelancer Project 1\Test Files\All_2.csv" WITH( DATAFILETYPE='char',FIRSTROW=2,FIELDTERMINATOR=',',ROWTERMINATOR='\r\n');```

Comment: @AmirWassim Your table has three columns, your csv file has two. I'm stopping now. You're clearly not doing any meaningful debugging yourself. (As shown when I asked about \r\n to begin with).

Comment: 1st this is my first time working with SQL server and first time migrating access to SQL and didn't notice that migration adds ssma timestamp column on its own and I deleted this column manually and it worked. Anyways my apologies and appreciate your time and effort